# How to generify the return type of a method that returns the object its called from

Tags: java, generics

If this question has already been asked i could not find it.
Here is a simplified example of what i am trying to do.

```
public static class SuperClass {
    private String name;

    public <? extends SuperClass> setName(String name)
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}

public static class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    private int id;

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

//Usage
SubClass subclass = new SubClass();
subClass.setName("Some Name").setId(0);
```

So what i need is for setName to return whatever class its actually called from as oppose to the class its defined in. (In this case it would return an instance of SubClass instead of SuperClass, but if for example SubClass was then extended by SubClass2 it would return an instance of SubClass2)

Is what im asking possible via generics?

Comment: `public static SuperClass{` doesn't compile `public <? extends SuperClass> setName(String name)` either.
 Please edit your code so that it compiles for basic things at least.

Comment: Not possible how you want it. You should look into the Builder Designpattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a type to the `SuperClass` declaration and use it in the returned type of the `setName()` method.
It will force all inherited subclass to return the type declared in their extending declaration to `SuperClass`.
But to achieve it you should cast `this` to `T` in `setName()`.

```
public class SuperClass<T extends SuperClass<T>> {
    private String name;

    public T setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      return (T) this;
    }
}
```

And declare subclass in this way :

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass<SubClass> {
     ...
    public void setId(int i) {
       ...
    }
   ...
}
```

And now you could do :

```
SubClass subclass = new SubClass();
subclass.setName("Some Name").setId(0);
```

---

Another way to address the problem :

Using covariant return types in the overrided methods will allow you to specify subclass in the returned type. You can use it instead of generics. 
The single thing to notice : you will have to be careful to define explicitly the return type by overriding the method in each subclass. 
Without generics, nothing will force you to do it (but an unit test).

```
public class SuperClass {
    private String name;

    public SuperClass setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      return this;
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    @Override
    public SubClass setName(String name) {
       super.setName(name);
       return this;
    }

    public void setId(int i) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Not possible. The class of `this` must not be the same as `T`

Comment: This is one of the things i tried. I was hoping for something that does not require the type to be set in the class deceleration, My ide also complains about the unchecked cast which makes no sense to me because T must extend SuperClass.

Comment: I think i will take @rollback 's suggestion of using a builder. It will have to be a generified builder as there will be a lot of different classes that extend the base class but it should be doable.
Edit: On second thought no a generified builder will not work at all... Obviously...

Comment: With generics use, setting as return type a specific subclass for each subclass requires to declare the type in the declaration of the super class extending. You have not choice. The "unsafe" downcast may also annoying but here still, it is the way which generics work in Java.

Comment: "a generified builder will not work at all". Indeed. But the covariant return type in the overrided methods will allow you to specify subclass in the returned type. You can use it instead of generics. The single thing to notice : you will have to be careful to define explicitly the return type in the overriden method. Without generics, nothing will force you to do it.

Comment: @brandon3055 I've made an Builder which can be used for every class that provides a no-argument constructor: https://pastebin.com/FJLNqRxa maybe that's something you want to use

Comment: @rollback nice and original way. Why not post an answer ? :) I would upvote. Now this has still some drawbacks. It is rather verbose for clients. `SuperClass::new` forces to expose a public constructor. Which is often not desirable for builders.

Comment: @davidxxx I can't add an answer because this is marked as an duplicate (which it really is, looking at the original question). But from the discussions under this questions it would still be a valid answer for this question :/

Comment: @rollback ah, sorry. I would like to vote to reopen as you did but I don't know how to do without using my Java gold badge privilege that will reopen instantly the question. I use this privilege only to close question appearing as real exact duplicates (for example not for this one).

Comment: @rollback ah, sorry. I would like to vote to reopen as you did but I don't know how to do without using my Java gold badge privilege that will reopen instantly the question. I use this privilege only to close question appearing as real exact duplicates (for example not this one). In fact, the question of the OP is rather oriented: "Is what im asking possible via generics? " and it may be considered as a duplicate. Now my answer with generics encourages the OP to change its mind. I think that he should either edit the question or reopen a new one by specifying that he looks for **any** solution

Comment: As mentioned the example provided is a simplified example. My actual use case is a lot more complicated with a lot of classes extending the base class and a lot of those sub classes are also extended by other classes. This means overriding the base methods in every sub class is really out of the question as i would end up with giant classes where 90% of the class is just overridden methods. 

The first solution suggested by @davidxxx works though i have run into an issue when trying to also make a sub class generic in the same way example issue: http://ss.brandon3055.com/jqsg34i.png

Comment: Never mind. I just figured it out. http://ss.brandon3055.com/3pxomcm.png Turns out that <T> is actually needed....